# Getting error on start activity

Tags: java, android

Getting error on My array Adapter class .The error is on Startavtivity line i dont know why it is    its working on other pahes but it shows error on this page .So could you please help me out

> ERROR" The Constructor `Intent(MyArrayAdapter,Class<Add_new_employee >undefined)`

```
package com.example.employeemanager;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MyArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Student> {

    Context context;
    int layoutResourceId;
    ArrayList<Student> students = new ArrayList<Student>();

    public MyArrayAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId,ArrayList<Student> studs)
    {
        super(context, layoutResourceId, studs);
        this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
        this.context = context;
        this.students = studs;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
    {
        View item = convertView;
        StudentWrapper StudentWrapper = null;

        if (item == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
            item = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);
            StudentWrapper = new StudentWrapper();
            StudentWrapper.name = (TextView) item.findViewById(R.id.textName);
            StudentWrapper.age = (TextView) item.findViewById(R.id.textAge);
            StudentWrapper.address = (TextView) item.findViewById(R.id.textAddr);
            StudentWrapper.edit = (Button) item.findViewById(R.id.btnEdit);
            StudentWrapper.delete = (Button) item.findViewById(R.id.btnDelete);
            StudentWrapper.checkBox = (CheckBox) item.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);         
            item.setTag(StudentWrapper);
        } 
        else
        {
            StudentWrapper = (StudentWrapper) item.getTag();
        }

        Student student = students.get(position);
        StudentWrapper.name.setText(student.getName());
        StudentWrapper.age.setText(student.getAge());
        StudentWrapper.address.setText(student.getAddress());

        StudentWrapper.edit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                startActivity(new Intent   
                            (MyArrayAdapter.this,Add_new_employee.class) );
            }
        });

        StudentWrapper.delete.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                }
            });

        StudentWrapper.checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton arg0, boolean arg1) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Checkox", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
        return item;
    }

    protected void startActivity(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    static class StudentWrapper
    {
        TextView name;
        TextView age;
        TextView address;
        Button edit;
        Button delete;
        CheckBox checkBox;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please always put your error with your code if you get any error.

Comment: sorry i cant post logcat  because its show error on the line not the run time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inseted of this

```
startActivity(new Intent   

                   (MyArrayAdapter.this,Add_new_employee.class) );
```

use this

```
context.startActivity(new Intent   

                   (context,Add_new_employee.class) );
```

**Note:** Make sure you had declared `Add_new_employee` in android manifest.xml

Comment: errror is gone but not going to another page

Comment: @AshishGeorge see my edited Answer. if problem persist please post your error log.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
startActivity(new Intent   
                   (getBaseContext(),Add_new_employee.class) );
```